# quadratic equation

Tags: equation, quadratic

Question: I have a program that solves a quadratic equation. The program gives real solutions only. How do I perform the quality testing of the program? Do you need to ask me for some extra input parameters?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not really clear what you are asking here. Your question will stand a better chance of being answered if you take some time to make it more clear and specific.

Answer (score 1):

Create test cases, and check the result of your program against the expected result (which is calculated externally) in the test case.

The test cases can cover several ordinary cases, together with special cases, such as when the coefficient is 0, or the discriminant is < 0, = 0, near 0. When you compare the result, make sure you handle the comparison properly (since the result is floating point numbers).

Answer (score 0):

```
# "quadratic-rb.rb" Code by RRB, dated April 2014. email ab_z@yahoo.com


class Quadratic

  def input
    print "Enter the value of a: "
    $a = gets.to_f

    print "Enter the value of b: "
    $b = gets.to_f

    print "Enter the value of c: "
    $c = gets.to_f
end


def announcement    #Method to display Equation
 puts "The formula is " + $a.to_s + "x^2 + " + $b.to_s + "x + " + $c.to_s + "=0"
end


def result    #Method to solve the equation and display answer

  if ($b**2-4*$a*$c)>0
  x1=(((Math.sqrt($b**2-4*$a*$c))-($b))/(2*$a))
  x2=(-(((Math.sqrt($b**2-4*$a*$c))-($b))/(2*$a)))
  puts "The values of x1 and x2 are " +x1.to_s + " and " + x2.to_s

else
  puts "x1 and x2 are imaginary numbers"
  end

end


Quadratic_solver = Quadratic.new
  Quadratic_solver.input
  Quadratic_solver.announcement
  Quadratic_solver.result
end
```